# Aligning subfigure and subtable

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, overleaf, subtables

I can place a subtable next to a subfigure, but I would like the figure and table to be aligned by their tops rather than their bottoms. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Image.png}
  \end{subfigure}

\hspace{-9cm}

  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{0.5mm} % for a less cramped "look"
  \fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont   %fontsize

    \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{C{1cm}|} }

    0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
    \hline
    0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
    1 & -1 & 1  & -1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

  \end{subtable}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Package `subfigure` is obsolete. Use `subfig` (which prowide `\subfloat` command) or even better `subcaption` which provide `subfigure` environment. BTW, so far your MWE doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, the arguments used correspond to subcaption package rather than the subfigure package.  But mostly you need to lose the blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Provided MWE doesn't work
- Package `subfigure` is obsolete. I suggest you that instead it use `subcaption` package
- Your question is not entirely clear:

  - Does your document have two lines? If not, than instead of `figure*` use just use `figure`!
  - Does `figure`, `subfigure` and `subtable` will not have captions?
  - If you like that the `subfigure` and `subtable` be paralel placed,  then between their code had not to be empty line.
- For top align of image and table top, you need to move picture baseline and tables to their tops.

Possible MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}      % <---

\usepackage{array}                  % <---
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=3ex]{subcaption}   % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image-duck}%{Image.png}
  \end{subfigure}
\hfill
  \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
  \fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont   % font size
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{b{1cm}|} }
    0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
    \hline
    0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
    1 & -1 & 1  & -1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is above showed compilation result what you after?

**Addendum:**

- It seems that my assumption about captions was wrong. Apparently OP like to have captions which should be vertical aligned similar as should be aligned image in table.
- This can be (relative simple) achieved by inserting image, table and their suncaptions into a table below

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}      % <---

\usepackage{tabularray}            % <---
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, counter, varwidth}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=-\abovecaptionskip}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] X[c]},
         rowsep  = 0pt, 
         measure = vbox % <---- that subcaptions works
        }
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image-duck}
    &  \begin{tblr}[t]{colspec={| *{4}{r}|} }
        \toprule
    0  &  1 & 0 &  1  \\
        \midrule
    0  &  1 & 0 &  1  \\
    1  & -1 & 1 & -1  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}               \\
\subcaption{figure}
    &   \subcaption{table}
    \end{tblr}
\caption{figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works until I add captions. With sub captions, the table drops to the bottom again.

Comment: @curry, I know. That was reason that  ask you "Does figure, subfigure and subtable will not have captions?" Since, if they have, solution had to be quite different. I will ad it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need subfloats at all? They are needed if you add subcaptions, but you have none.

To get top alignment, lower both the image and the `tabular` by their height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]

\setlength\extrarowheight{0.5mm} % for a less cramped "look"
\large

\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image}%
}\hfill
\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{w{c}{1cm}|} }
  \hline
  0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
  \hline
  0  & 1 & 0  & 1  \\
  1 & -1 & 1  & -1 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\caption{A figure with an accompanying table}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You don't say what `C` is, but I guess it's for centered columns with fixed width: use `w{c}{<width>}` instead.

[image]